# SQL Count and Pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table and it has a column that only has 2 kinds of input: New and Old. It looks like this:

```
old_or_new
----------
  old
  old
  new
  new
  old
```

I want to count the numbers of old and new and pivot the table to look like this:

```
column_name | total
--------------------
   old      |   3
   new      |   2
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

What I did is this:

```
select
    count(case when old_or_new = 'Old' then 1 else 0 end) as old,
    count(case when old_or_new = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) as new
from members
```

The result is this:

```
old | new
----------
 3  |  2
```

Comment: Which DBMS? What have you tried already?

Comment: MySQL database. I tried pivoting but its not the result that I wanted. Let me edit my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most basic form of a group by query:

```
select old_or_new as column_name,
       count(*) as total
from the_table
group by old_or_new;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9469c/1

Comment: This is it! Thank you!